# Can I use a sharepoint list as the data source for getorgchart

Tags: getorgchart

Can I use a sharepoint list as the data source for GetOrgChart?  I want to build and maintain the data in sharepoint and then put this js into sharepoint to create a aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could,You would need to return all the list data in JSON using the SharePoint REST API or an Ajax request and the relevant Headers in the request.

dataType: "json",

you would then have to make sure the JSON structure matches that of the Orgchart examples using the developer tools in the browser or fiddler.

When you create your list use the same columns names of that getorgchart supports.